# Safe and Clean way to run a function from JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have this simple html button.

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Start</button>
```

**When I click the button** I want to run a function in a Java File. Should I put my code in the JSP File like:

```
   <%
   ClassName className = new ClassName();
   className.function();
   %>
```

If I need to pass a parameter from the HTML I need to do a doGet or doPost just for one parameter? or there's a better and simpler way?

Comment: You mix up things that happen in your browser and in the server. When you click a button this is in the browser. A request has to be sent to the server so it knows about it. You can do that for example by putting the button into a form that will then send the request.

Comment: ok so I have to do AJAX post right?

Comment: AJAX is another possible way.

Comment: How have you set up your app? show us the web.xml and more

Answer (score 0):

your button must be in a form with `action='yourUrlToServlet'` or you send the request with AJAX. Then you need a servlet that receives the request. In the servlet you can make a call to some method.

Maybe this page can help to understand it: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info